# Delaunay triangulation from an EMST

Tags: computational-geometry, minimum-spanning-tree, triangulation

Assume you know the Euclidean Minimum Spanning Tree of a set of $n$ 2D points (in general position).

Is there an efficient way (faster than $O(n \log n)$ operations) to obtain the Delaunay triangulation of these points ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_minimum_spanning_tree) states, that:

> the Delaunay triangulation can be constructed from the Euclidean minimum spanning tree in the near-linear time bound $O(n\log ^{*}n)$, where $\log ^{*}$ denotes the [Iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm).

This article refers to the [paper](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00167206/file/hal.pdf), where you can find a randomized algorithm for the problem you're interested in.

Comment: Yep, I missed that. Thanks !